# Create iOS MDM Server on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, enterprise, mdm

I am new with iOS technology. I am working on iOS MDM server. Currently i setup the server with https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server .

As i understood, NWAPNSWrapper create a payload message which include the message, pushcert, push magic and device token with web server.

Can i create web application on iphone and push similar message to same phone if required information available with app.

As i tried below thing.
- With safari browser it is opening the policy mobile config file and install it.
I installed the enroll.config and ca with local server. But when i push password policy mobile config it is not installing silent and not associated with installed enroll.config.

I want to push policy mobile config on same device. 
How can i associate the mdm push notification from ios device to APNS and APNS to ios device.